# Iterate over nested objects - if field matches variable, update $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects used in an `ng-repeat`. Each object will have an array of nested objects with one field. An example:

```
{
  "_id": "55927dc3d2d258ac62fcdb36",
  "title": "Some title",
  "username": "test1",
  "voted": [
    {
      "username": "bill" 
    },
    {
      "username": "ben" 
    },
    {
      "username": "sarah" 
    }
  ]
},
{ 
  "_id": "55927dc3d2d258ac62fcdabc",
  "title": "Another title",
  "voted": [
    {
      "username": "someone" 
    }
  ]
},
{ 
  "_id": "55927dc3d2d258ac62fcddef",
  "title": "Something else",
  "voted": []
}
```

For each object, i'd like to check if one of the nested objects in the `voted` array has a value that matches a variable outside of the array completely.  If a match is found, I want to push a new field to the object in question (outside of the `voted` array), so that a 'flag' can be displayed to the user.

[I have an example 'working', but not as I want it to](http://jsfiddle.net/7jv67y6b/1/). I iterate over each item with `angular.forEach`, then iterate over `voted`, and check if any of the `voted.username` fields match `$scope.randomNameExample`. If a match is found, I push a new object to `$scope.items`:

```
$scope.randomNameExample = 'bill';

var items = [
  { ... },
  { ... },
  { ... },
  { ... }
];

$scope.items = items;

angular.forEach(items, function(item) {

  angular.forEach(item.voted, function(voted) {

        if(voted.username === $scope.randomNameExample) {
          console.log("username is the same - push $scope!");
          var matchingUsernamesObj = {matchingUsernames: true};

          $scope.items.push(matchingUsernamesObj);
          console.log(this);

        }

  }, $scope.items);

}, $scope.items);
```

The template:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <p>{{item.title}}</p>
    <p>by {{item.username}}</p>

    <!-- if item.voted[X].username matches randomNameExample, show this element -->

    <p ng-show="item.matchingUsernames" class="its-happened">already voted.</p>

</li>
```

This works - the 'flag' displays in the relevant items, but the rest of the item's object is completely overridden.

Why is this happening?

How can I ensure that when I push a new object, the original object stays intact?

I'll probably want to push a new field rather than an object, but it'd be nice to know about both.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jv67y6b/1/)

Also, is there a better way to achieve such results with pure angular? I'm sure there are some nice lodash methods for this kind of thing, but I don't want to introduce lodash right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you add a new item without any title or username to the list whenever a match is found. I don't know whether that's intentional, but you probably just want to set the `matchingUsernames` property on the `item` which had a match.

```
angular.forEach(items, function(item) {

  angular.forEach(item.voted, function(voted) {

        if(voted.username === $scope.randomNameExample) {
          item.matchingUsernames = true;
        }

  }, $scope.items);

}, $scope.items);
```

Here is an updated version of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0y8kbed5/).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is loads better and clears some things up in my mind.. I think I got a fuzzy after looking for a while. :-)